# Blazor UI issue, how do I force the required error message on my dropdown select statement when user does not select an option?

Tags: c#, blazor

I am using Blazor UI. here is my Dropdown markup:
The issue I am referring to is that if the user does NOT make a selection, in other words the _bid.ProductLineId is null and the default "Select a Product Line" is displayed, the [Required] property in the Model (BidViewModel) should fire the message: **Product Line is required**, but it does not. The on change method is firing, but not the message. Any suggestions?

```
<ContentTemplate>
      <EditForm Model="@_bid" OnValidSubmit="@SaveBid" class="animate-fade" Context="editFrmBidConfirmation">
         <DataAnnotationsValidator />
         <ServerValidator @ref="serverValidator" />
         <ValidationSummary />
         <BSContainer>
            <BSRow>
               <BSCol MD="2" Class="form-label">Product Line:</BSCol>
               <BSCol MD="4">
                   <select id="ProductLine" @onchange="@ProductLineChange" value="@_bid.ProductLineId">
                       <option value=null>Select a Product Line</option>
                       @foreach (ProductLine a in _productLines)
                       {
                           <option value="@a.Id">@a.Name</option>
                       }
                   </select>
               </BSCol>
```

Here is the initialization:

```
private BidViewModel _bid { get; set; }
private List<Data.Models.ProductLine> _productLines { get; set; }
_productLines = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Data.Models.ProductLine>>(await apiClient.GetProductLinesForUserAsync(userId));
_productLineSelected = (_bid.ProductLineId != null);
```

Here is the method to fire on change: @ProductLineChange, note "e" is null, thus _bid.ProductLineId is set to null in the BidViewModel.

```
private async Task ProductLineChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _bid.ProductLineId = e.Value.ToString();
        _productLineSelected = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bid.ProductLineId));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bid.ProductLineId))
        {

            _bidClasses = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Bid_Class>>(await apiClient.GetBidClassesAsync(_bid.ProductLineId));
            _bidStatuses = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Bid_StatusViewModel>>(await apiClient.GetBidStatusesAsync(_bid.ProductLineId));
            _bidTypes = await processor.ProcessObject<List<Bid_Type>>(await apiClient.GetBidTypesAsync(_bid.ProductLineId));
            _distributorGroups = new();
            _distributors = await processor.ProcessObject<List<DistributorViewModel>>(await apiClient.GetDistributorsByProductLineAsync(_bid.ProductLineId));
        } 

        RefreshScreen(null);

    }
```

Lastly Here is the ViewModel: BidViewModel

```
public class BidViewModel : Bid
   {
      public BidViewModel()
      {
         Notes_Internal = new List<BidNoteInternal>();
         Notes_Pricing = new List<BidNotePricing>();
         Items = new List<Bid_Item>();
         Bid_Locations = new List<Bid_Location>(); //11/30/2021 SEO 681529
         Bid_Distributor_Entities = new List<Bid_Distributor_Entity>(); //03/20/2022 SEO 681533
        }
        // 12/22/2022 PTR 1060058 - Resolve Framework Warning, always start with Capital
        public bool IsExisting { get; set; }

      public bool Equals(Bid other)
      {
         if (this.Id == other.Id)
         {
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
```

Bid class which is inherited by BidViewModel:

```
namespace BQM.Data.Models
{
   [Display(Name = "Bid")]
   public class Bid : BaseAuditEntity<string>, IValidatableObject
   {
      public Bid()
      {
         Id = "Generated";
         DateCreated = 
         DateModified =
         Date_BidOpened = DateTime.Now.Date; //09/22/2021 SEO 786208 - Strip time portion to allow for proper filter
         Date_BidPriceStart = DateTime.Now;
         Distributor_GroupId = "";
         DistributorId = "";
         Notes_Internal = new List<BidNoteInternal>();
         Notes_Pricing = new List<BidNotePricing>();
         Items = new List<Bid_Item>();
         SalesPeople = new List<BidToSalesPeople>();
         IsPercentageOff = false;
         Active = true;
         IsQuote = false;
         PercentageOff = 0;
         ProgramAdjustment = false;

         //11/30/2021 SEO 681529
         Bid_Locations = new List<Bid_Location>();

         //03/20/2022 SEO 681533
         Bid_Distributor_Entities = new List<Bid_Distributor_Entity>();
        }

        [Key]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bid ID is required.")]
      [Display(Name = "New Bid #")]
      [Column("BidId")]
      [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The New Bid # can only be 10 characters (or less)")]
      public override string Id { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Old Bid #")]
      [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The Old Bid # can only be 10 characters (or less)")]
      public string OldBidNumber { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bid Type is required.")]
      public string Bid_TypeId { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Type")]
      public virtual Bid_Type Bid_Type { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bid Class is required.")]
      public string Bid_ClassId { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Class")]
      public virtual Bid_Class Bid_Class { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Line is required.")]
      public string ProductLineId { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Product Line")]
      public virtual ProductLine ProductLine { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Account Name is required.")]
      [StringLength(75, ErrorMessage = "Account Name can't be longer than 75 characters")]
      public string Account { get; set; }
        
      //09/16/2021 SEO - Added distributed group requirement
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Distributor Group is required.")]
      public string Distributor_GroupId { get; set; }

      public virtual Distributor_Group Distributor_Group { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Distributor is required.")]
      [Display(Name = "Distributor #")]
      public string DistributorId { get; set; }

      public virtual Distributor Distributor { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sales Rep. is required.")]
      public string SalesPersonDefaultId { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Sales Rep.")]
      public virtual SalesPerson SalesPersonDefault { get; set; }
      public virtual List<BidToSalesPeople> SalesPeople { get; set; }

      public bool ProgramAdjustment { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "National/Local Programs")]
      //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Nat Prg is required.")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5,2)")]
      public decimal? Programs { get; set; }

      public string Notes_External { get; set; }
      public string Notes_External_Footer { get; set; }

      public virtual List<BidNotePricing> Notes_Pricing { get; set; }

      public virtual List<BidNoteInternal> Notes_Internal { get; set; }

      public virtual List<Bid_Item> Items { get; set; } //12/23/2021 SEO Refactor Bid Item Implementation - Changed from Collection To List

        [Display(Name = "Bid Opened")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
      public DateTime Date_BidOpened { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Accepted")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
      public DateTime? Date_BidAccepted { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Expires")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
      public DateTime? Date_BidExpires { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Pricing Start")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
      public DateTime? Date_BidPriceStart { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Pricing End")]
      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
      public DateTime? Date_BidPriceEnd { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Price Esc.")]
      public string PriceEscalation { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Is the Price Guaranteed?")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price Guarantee is required.")]
      public bool PriceGuarantee { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Is this a Percentage Off?")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is Percentage Off is required.")]
      public bool IsPercentageOff { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Percentage Off")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Specific Percentage Off is required.")]
      [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5,2)")]
      public decimal PercentageOff { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Bid Active")]
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is Bid Active required.")]
      public bool Active { get; set; }

      [Display(Name = "Quote?")]
      public bool IsQuote { get; set; }

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bid Status required.")]
      public string Bid_StatusId { get; set; }
      [Display(Name = "Bid Status")]
      public virtual Bid_Status Bid_Status { get; set; }

      public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
         if (!IsQuote && Date_BidAccepted == null)
         {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You must have an Accepted Date before saving this record as a Bid", new string[] { "Date_BidAccepted" });
         }
         if (PriceGuarantee && Date_BidPriceEnd == null)
         {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You must have an End Date for Price Guaranteed bids/quotes", new string[] { "Date_BidPriceEnd" });
         }
         if (!Active && Date_BidExpires == null)
         {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You must have an Expire Date for Inactive bids/quotes", new string[] { "Date_BidExpires" });
         }
      }

        //11/30/2021 SEO 681529
        public virtual List<Bid_Location> Bid_Locations { get; set; }

        //03/20/2022 SEO 681533
        public virtual List<Bid_Distributor_Entity> Bid_Distributor_Entities { get; set; }
    }
   public class BidToSalesPeople : IEquatable<BidToSalesPeople>
   {
      [Key]
      public string BidId { get; set; }

      public virtual Bid Bid { get; set; }

      [Key]
      public string SalesPersonId { get; set; }

      public virtual SalesPerson SalesPerson { get; set; }

      public bool Equals(BidToSalesPeople other)
      {
         Contract.Requires(other != null);
         if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
         if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
         return this.BidId == other.BidId &&
            this.SalesPersonId == other.SalesPersonId;
      }

      public override bool Equals(object obj)
      {
         return Equals(obj as BidToSalesPeople);
      }

      public override int GetHashCode()
      {
         return new Tuple<string, string>(SalesPersonId, BidId).GetHashCode();
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the RefreshScreen(null);

```
private void RefreshScreen(ModalResult modalResult)
    {
        if (modalResult is null || !modalResult.Cancelled)
        {
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you submit the form without selecting the option whats happend?

Comment: I haven't tried that as of yet. I am pretty certain that the message will pop. With two other dropdowns that are using Telerik Combobox, is updated and the user does not make a selection, the required message appears, I want the same action with Product Line which is using the Select Statement. In add mode, I have a different issue, even when the user makes a selection the message never disappears.

Comment: The required message appears after you do one modification in one of the form fields. If you want to force it, you could  exectute the EditContext.Validate(); but for doing that you  have to create and use on the EditForm the EditContext prop instead the Model and assing by code the model to the EditContext

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit of a wall of code so I may have missed something important!

There's no such thing as `null` in html so:

```html
<option value=null>Select a Product Line</option>
```

actually sets `ProductLineId` to "null" if selected, which is a valid value for the validator.

Here's some code that I use that "forces" a choice decision on Selects.  It's standalone so you can copy and paste it into a page and see it in action.

Once you go to the dropdown you have to choose a value.  If you exit without selecting by tabbing no value is set so it's still null and fails validation.  Once a value is selected the "-- Select a Product Line --" option disappears.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model=this.model>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <select class="form-select mb-2" value="@model.ProductLineId" @onchange=this.ProductLineChange>
        @if (model.ProductLineId is null)
        {
            <option disabled selected value="">-- Select a Product Line --</option>
        }
        @foreach (ProductLine a in _productLines)
        {
            <option value="@a.Id">@a.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
    <ValidationMessage For="() => this.model.ProductLineId" />
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

<div>
    @model.ProductLineId
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new();

    private async Task ProductLineChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.model.ProductLineId = e.Value?.ToString() ?? null;

        // emulate some async work
        await Task.Delay(200);
    }


    public class Model
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Line is required.")]
        public string? ProductLineId { get; set; }
    }

    private List<ProductLine> _productLines = new()
    {
        new() { Name = "French" },
        new() { Name = "English" },
        new() { Name = "Spanish" },
        new() { Name = "Swedish" },
    };

    public record ProductLine
    {
        public string Id { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public string Name { get; init; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You should be able to use this to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I am actually trying to clean up something that someone else built. So, I am going to try this. I will let you kow.